# Inserting multiple data into table with SELECT and JOIN statement

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I would like to insert data into table with one of the columns being populated by a select query. This is my SQL statement:

```
INSERT INTO books ( gid, type, membernumber,  changedate, user)
  VALUES( '2b4493e8-cae8-4624-8177-fcc96553c5be',
          2,
          (SELECT member FROM mem m JOIN group g ON m.uid = g.sgroup),
          TIMESTAMP '2017-01-03 00:00:00.000',
          'mark'
        );
```

What I want to achieve is for each insert, the `membernumber` will be taken from the `mem` table base on the `JOIN` it has with the `group` table.

When I execute this statement, I get the error:

> More than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

So for instance if the join will produce 20 rows then 20 records will be inserted with each `member` value replacing the `membernumber` in the insert for the 20 rows.

### Update

I also have another query where two columns have to be replaced with SELECT-JOIN statements. @Tim has given me an example of one column. I want an example with two columns been filled with two SELECT-JOIN statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may rephrase this as an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO books (gid, type, membernumber, changedate, user)
SELECT
    '2b4493e8-cae8-4624-8177-fcc96553c5be',
    2,
    member,
    '2017-01-03 00:00:00.000',
    'mark'
FROM mem m
INNER JOIN `group` g
    ON m.uid = g.sgroup;
```

This should fix your syntax error, but now you have to decide whether this insert makes any sense without a `WHERE` clause.  You are hard coding almost every field for each member.

Comment: thanks for your reply. My next question is, is it possible to do the same with 2 or more Select-Join statements in the same query because i have another issue similar to the first but now with 3 Select-Join statement. Can you show me an example using the query above but lets assume "user" will have SELECT-Join like membernumber. Thanks

Comment: @EddyFreeman I don't completely follow your comment, but it looks like a non trivial departure from this question.  You may want to ask a new question.