# Inserting multiple Data Into Table with Multiple Select and Join Statements

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

This is a follow up question to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50695066/inserting-multiple-data-into-table-with-select-and-join-statement)
I would like to insert data into table with three of the columns being populated by a select-join queries. This is my sql statement::

```
INSERT INTO books ( gid, type, membernumber,  changedate, order, user, task)
  VALUES( '2b4493e8-cae8-4624-8177-fcc96553c5be',
          2,
          (SELECT member FROM mem m JOIN group g ON m.uid = g.sgroup),
          TIMESTAMP '2017-01-03 00:00:00.000',
          (SELECT order FROM orders o JOIN items i ON o.id = i.id),
          'mark',
          (SELECT task FROM tasks t JOIN lists l ON t.id = l.id),
        );
```

What i want to achieve is for each insert, the membernumber, order and task will be taken from the mem, order and tasks tables base on the JOIN it has with their respective join tables.

Comment: tag the specific database which you are using

Comment: How are the tables `member`, `orders` and `task` related? If you can build a **single** query that returns the desired rows from those tables, you can easily use that as the source of an insert statement (instead of the `values` clause)

Comment: @a_horse This is just an example. The relationship is not important. I just want the correct syntax.

Comment: The relationship **is** important. Only if you are able to create a single query that returns the information you want to insert, you can do this properly. As shown your query makes no sense whatsoever. You are inserting a single row, but retrieving multiple rows from those "related" tables and you are trying to put the columns values for **many** rows into one column of a **single** row.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name like i said the above code is just an example. in the real code there is relationship. Assume there is a relationship in the above code, what will the correct syntax be? I am looking for the correct syntax

Comment: `insert into some_table (col1, col2, ...) select .... from join ...`